# Tizen .Net Mobile Development

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tizen, tizen-emulator

I'm using Tizen.Net Development by using Visual Studio 2017.

Currently, I had developed Tizen Mobile application with Xamarin.Forms.

I'm facing a few problems:

1. The emulator runs so slow
2. Intel HAXM can't install
3. The documentation is not so complete

How to setup the emulator for Tizen? Because after I setup the emulator is different from others that present during Build / Connect event.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I have voted to close this question. Please have a loot at the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on how to formulate a proper question. With the one you have posted now you just throw a lot of problems out there without any additional information that can help us, help you solve the problem. Additionally, it does not show any effort on your part; what have you tried already? Where did you fail? Do you get any errors? Logs? And what do they say?

Answer (score 0):

I know the solution to solve this problems.
Follow its step by step.

1. You must disable your Hyper-V
2. Restart your computer
3. Create a new Tizen Emulator
4. Launch Tizen Emulator.